# Rails isn't appending cache-busting timestamp to assets in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline

I'm using stylesheet_link_tag with the asset pipeline and yet I get this:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

My production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
```

I'm assuming it's the settings or something simple..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure this setting is true:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.digest = true
```

and that you've run `rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: Thanks.  I was surprised my google searches didn't show this, hopefully it will now for the next guy.

Comment: @NathanWienert Out of curiosity, was it the config setting or the Rake task?

Comment: @Brandan Late response, but for the next person: my asset compilation rake task was generating the cache-buster at the end (based on `ls public/assets`) before changing the config as above, but was not using until I changed the config and restarted my server.